# Working of missed call based phone number verification

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-dialer, sms-verification

In recent times, we are seeing a phone number is verified using a missed call given on clients mobile number and it shows phone number is verified. How does this process happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A broadcast receiver `(receiver)` is an Android component which allows you to register for system or application events. All registered receivers for an event are notified by the Android `runtime` once this event happens.
So, the app which you are using for verification register a broadcast receiver for `(on call recieve)` call and as soon as it happens, the android system notify the app.

More infos on google [developer](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts)

Here is an [example](https://gist.github.com/ftvs/e61ccb039f511eb288ee)